# Flutter error with ListView.builder(). error: Bottom Overflowed by 279 pixels

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class TransactionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> _transaction;

  TransactionWidget(this._transaction);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 500,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Card(
                child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    '\$${_transaction[index].amount.toString()}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.lightBlue)),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                ), // amount ICON (Left)
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      _transaction[index].title,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                    ), // Text Title
                    Text(
                      DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(_transaction[index].date),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.grey),
                    ), // Text Date
                  ],
                ) // Text of Title and Date
              ],
            ));
          },
          itemCount: _transaction.length,
        ));
  }
}
```

I am building a flutter app that shows a list of transactions entered by the user. The following code is to build and display multiple transactions, however whenever I open the keyboard to enter a new transaction the overflow error occurs. Above the transaction list I have added the 'Card' widget that takes the user input and adds a new transaction.
[The screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpcJ9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, 
  ... 
)
```

This will avoid resizing when keyboard opens and thus avoid any overflows

Answer (score 0):

You are using a fixed size in your `Container`, the '`height: 500`', so don't care if you are using a `ListView`.
Try to remove if you can, because the `ListView` will manage the size.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a height for your listview container to 500, you can wrap your listview container with the Expanded widget, this will adjust the listview to changes in the screen size and orientation.